# Call graph doxygen in fortran95

Tags: fortran, doxygen, call-graph

I am documenting my Fortran code using Doxygen. I am new to this program and I find it great. Actually, I am stack with the call_graph functionality for a subroutine.

I have set the following options as suggested in the user guide:

```
HAVE_DOT=YES
EXTRACT_ALL=YES
CALL_GRAPH=YES
OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN=YES
```

But it doesn't work correctly since any graph appears. Have you got any experince with this or suggestions?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Some more information is needed. Which version of doxygen are you using. Please add a small example program (just e,g, a program calling a subroutine).. Did you document the routines? otherwise have a look at the settings `EXTRACT_....`

Comment: Hello Albert, actually I do not have access to the pc and  I will get you back tomorrow. The code is pretty large and no subroutine can actually display a call graph. The version is 1.8.14 (windows). Thank you very much!